# Error when trying to jit the computation of the Jacobian in JAX: "ValueError: Non-hashable static arguments are not supported"

Tags: python, jax

This question is similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65685211/non-hashable-static-arguments-are-not-supported-in-jax-when-using-vmap), but I cannot link with what I should alter.

I have a function

```
def elbo(variational_parameters, eps, a, b):
    ...
    return theta, _

elbo = jit(elbo, static_argnames=["a", "b"])
```

where `variational_parameters` is a vector (one-dimensional array) of length P, `eps` is a two-dimensional array of dimensions K by N, and `a`, `b` are fixed values.

The `elbo` has been *successfully* `vmap`ped over the rows of `eps`, and has been `jit`ted by setting by passing `a` and `b` to `static_argnames`, to return `theta`, which is a two-dimensional array of dimensions K by P.

I want to take the Jacobian of the output `theta` with respect to `variational_parameters` through the `elbo` function. The first value returned by

```
jacobian(elbo, argnums=0, has_aus=True)(variational_parameters, eps, a, b)
```

gives me a three-dimensional array of dimensions K by P by N. This is what I want. As soon as I try to jit this function

```
jit(jacobian(elbo, argnums=0, has_aus=True))(variational_parameters, eps, a, b)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Non-hashable static arguments are not supported, which can lead to unexpected cache-misses. Static argument (index 2) of type <class 'jax.interpreters.partial_eval.DynamicJaxprTracer'> for function elbo is non-hashable.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any parameters you pass to a JIT-compiled function will no longer be static, unless you explicitly mark them as such. So this line:

```py
jit(jacobian(elbo, argnums=0, has_aus=True))(variational_parameters, eps, a, b)
```

Makes `variational_parameters`, `eps`, `a`, and `b` non-static. Then within the transformed function these non-static parameters are passed to this function:

```py
elbo = jit(elbo, static_argnames=["a", "b"])
```

which means that you are attempting to pass non-static values as static arguments, which causes an error.

To fix this, you should mark the static parameters as static any time they enter a jit-compiled function. In your case it might look something like this:

```py
jit(jacobian(elbo, argnums=0, has_aus=True),
    static_argnums=(2, 3))(variational_parameters, eps, a, b)
```

Comment: Hi Jake, thank you for the response; it works as expected! I have a follow-up question . I neglected to say in my question that I had tried ```jit(jacobian(elbo, argnums=0, has_aus=True), static_argnames=["a", "b"])(variational_parameters, eps, a, b)``` and got the same error that I mentioned in the question. The solution was to pass the static arguments via `static_argnums` instead of `static_argnames`. Why is this? Do the variables not have the same name when called using a wrapped function like the jacobian?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this – I think this should work, but the `jacobian` decorator is currently missing `functools.wraps` on its output. I'll plan to add a fix for that later today.

Comment: This should be fixed by https://github.com/google/jax/pull/12653